# What are the differences between injecting the default route to IGP using a static route or using a generated route?

Tags: routing, juniper, design

Let's say, that I have a following network topology:

```
isp_router[t1-0/0/0.0] <-> [t1-0/0/0.0]ospf_asbr
```

I want to generate a default route for IGP in `ospf_asbr` router. One option would be a static route:

```
root@Dubbel> show configuration routing-options
rib inet.0 {
    static {
        /* 84.10.113.1 is configured on isp_router interface t1-0/0/0.0 */
        route 0.0.0.0/0 next-hop 84.10.113.1;
    }
}

root@Dubbel>
```

Another option should be a generated route with policy filter which allows only the 84.10.113.0/31 as a contributing route. For example, like this:

```
[edit]
root@Dubbel# show routing-options generate 
route 0.0.0.0/0 policy gen_default;

[edit]
root@Dubbel# show policy-options policy-statement gen_default
term 1 {
    from {
        protocol direct;
        route-filter 84.10.113.0/31 exact;
    }
    then accept;
}
term 2 {
    then reject;
}

[edit]
root@Dubbel#
```

Is one approach better than other? Both should withdraw the default route from the IGP if the link between the `isp_router` and `ospf_asbr` fails. Or in general, what are the differences between injecting the default route to IGP using a static route or using a generated route?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Static route

This route will be installed as long as its next-hop is reachable.  The default route [Preference](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/reference/general/routing-protocols-default-route-preference-values.html) is 5.

Static routes are simpler and are appropriate when there's no routing protocol running between you and your transit provider.

## Aggregate route

[Aggregate](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/reference/configuration-statement/aggregate-edit-routing-options.html) routes are only installed if at least one contributing route is active.  The contributors, by default, are any route longer-than the configured aggregate, so `192.0.2.0/25` would be a valid contributor to `192.0.2.0/24`.  Aggregate routes have default Preference 130.

The next-hop of aggregate routes is discard or a next-table.

Contributing routes may be filtered through a policy, as you describe in your question.

## Generate route

[Generate](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/reference/configuration-statement/generate-edit-routing-options.html) routes are like Aggregates.  The distinction is generate routes adopt the next-hop of their primary contributing route.

The primary contributing route is the one with the lowest Preference, and after that, the lowest subnet address.

Generate routes are useful for configuring a default route toward transit which will be withdrawn (or replaced by a generate route with a differing next-hop) if, for example, an associated transit provider BGP session announcing at least one contributing route stops announcing them, or goes down.